# Alert sendo repetido através do .each() ajax

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$("#apagar-marcados").click(function(){
    var lista_marcados = document.getElementsByName('id_mensagem[]');
    $.each(lista_marcados, function(i, item){
        if ($(item).prop('checked')){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL + "ajax/remover_mensagem",
                data:{id_mensagem: $(item).val()}, 
                cache: false,

                success: function(){
                    alert('atualizado')
                }
            });                 
        }
    });
});
```

Nisto, eu faço a atualização via SQL no banco de dados, até então, funciona perfeitamente.
Neste caso, tenho uma listagem com checkbox, que por sua vez, marcados, com o clique no botão de excluir, entrará nesta ação.

O problema é, que se eu selecionar 10 checkbox, aparecerá o `alert('atualizado')` 10x, como eu faço para aparecer apenas uma vez?

Comment: O retorno da função `$.ajax` é um *promise*, então você pode tentar utilizar o [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), mas por quê não enviar todos os valores na mesma requisição já?

Comment: Porque não sei como fazer isto @AndersonCarlosWoss, no PHP eu sei fazer atualizar todos os que vierem no post(id_mensagem) através da array, mas não sei repassar a array().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deves considerar enviar apenas 1 ajax para o servidor e deixar o servidor fazer as mudanças na base de dados. Se essa aplicação for grande e tiveres muitos utilizadores a enviar N ajax dessa maneira pode ser pesado para o servidor gerir.

Para enviar só 1 ajax podias fazer assim:

```js
$("#apagar-marcados").click(function() {
  var lista_marcados = document.getElementsByName('id_mensagem[]');
  var marcados = [].filter.apply(lista_marcados, function(item) {
    return item.checked;
  }).map(function(item) {
    return item.value;
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL + "ajax/remover_mensagem",
    data: {marcados: marcados},
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
      alert('atualizado')
    }
  });

});
```

Mas respondendo à tua pergunta podes fazer assim:

```js
$("#apagar-marcados").click(function() {
  var items = $('[name="id_mensagem[]"]').get();
  var ajaxs = items.reduce(function(arr, item) {
    if (!item.checked) return arr;
    const ajax = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: BASE_URL + "ajax/remover_mensagem",
      data: {id_mensagem: item.value},
      cache: false
    });
    return arr.concat(ajax);
  }, []);

  $.when.apply($, ajaxs).done(function() {
    alert('Concluído!');
  });
});
```

Comment: dessa forma, estarás enviando por array() os itens ou estará enviando da forma que eu já faço hoje?

Comment: @AndréBaill assim é como fazes hoje (como na pergunta).

Comment: Ok, dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente, porém, o @AndersonCarlosWoss me disse que devo enviar tudo junto, para o PHP Tratar e atualizar. Como seria feito?

Comment: @AndréBaill juntei à resposta.

Comment: Perfeito @Sergio, muito grato, é isso mesmo! :)